# Asp.net MVC MiniProfiler "Request is not available in this context"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I am trying to use MiniProfiler for my MVC application which is using Oracle DB. Here is my global.asax .

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();    
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);            
         MiniProfiler.Start(); //or any number of other checks, up to you 

    }
    protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DevExpressHelper.Theme = "Metropolis";
        MiniProfiler.Stop(); //stop as early as you can, even earlier with MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.Stop(discardResults: true);

    }
```

When application starts i am getting :

> "Request is not available in this context"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are running `MiniProfiler.Start()` in the wrong place. You need to run `MiniProfiler.Start()` as part of `Application_BeginRequest`. Move it to this function and it should work.

When you run it as part of `Application_Start` it fails, because it is trying to access `HttpContext.Current`, which is not accessible in `Application_Start`.

In the context of MiniProfiler, `Application_Start` is a good place to make any global `MiniProfiler.Setting` customizations that you would like to have in place for all requests.